# Lookup method resolution failed in Spring Boot with JAXB

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jaxb

I'm getting the following error when trying to use a JAXB-generated class inside a Spring Boot controller:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-25 17:22:51.417 ERROR 10300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataMappingController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.example.mapping.DataMappingController] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1285) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.example.mapping.LareferenciaDataMappingApplication.main(LareferenciaDataMappingApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.example.mapping.DataMappingController] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

The controller code:

```
@RestController
public class DataMappingController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/mapping")
    public void dataMapping() {
        
        try{
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(EntityRelationData.class);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `EntityRelationData` class is generated by JAXB in `target/generated-sources/jaxb`, so I added it as a source directory in the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>data-mapping</name>
    <description>Data model mapping from LARerencia to Vivo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/jaxb</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/brcris_data_schema.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>    
                
  </build>

</project>
```

I guess something is still missing in the configuration, but I'm clueless about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out it was missing some dependencies. Added the following to the pom.xml and it worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: #transitiveDependencies Gaaa!  Thanks.